# Formal power series over p-adic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Does $\mathbb Z_p \otimes \mathbb Z[[x]]=\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$ hold?

In particular, I don't know how to express $\sum\frac 1{q^n}x^n$ for $q\ne p$ as an element of the tensor product.

Or it should be $\mathbb Z_p \hat\otimes \mathbb Z[[x]]=\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$?

Comment: the title says $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ but the post says $\Bbb Z[x]$ so which is it ?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I meant $\mathbb Z[[x]]$.

Comment: No, your desired equality (or isomorphism) doesn’t hold. You need the completed tensor product, $\Bbb Z_p\hat\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z[[x]]$. Remember that something is in the (uncompleted) tensor product exactly if it’s a *finite* sum of basic tensors $a\otimes b$.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks a lot